# MYSQL - How to avoid primary id wastages?

Tags: mysql, load, auto-increment

How to avoid skipping primary ids when inserting records through multiple load statements?

I inserted a file containing 150 records through LOAD statement into a table.

The last primary id in the table after insertion is 150.

Now, when I insert another file with 100 records through the load statement, the primary id assigned to the first record is 251 instead of 151.

How do I avoid these primary id wastage?

More information:
e.g:

```
mysql> desc test_data;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| image      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My Load statement -

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/test_2.dat' 
       INTO TABLE test_data 
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
       set created_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Sample data in the file test_2.dat:

```
|Peter|peter.jpg
|sam|sam.jpg
|radnor|radnor.jpg
|bruce|bruce.jpg
```

This is the table structure after the load of that file.

```
mysql> show create table test_data;

| test_data | CREATE TABLE `test_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Now, the max(id) in this table is 4. But why is the AUTO_INCREMENT value now set to to "8"? Should it not be set to "5"?

Comment: can you please elaborate little more.

Comment: my friend you are complicating youself, y don't use autoincrement?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the AUTO_INCREMENT to true on the primary id to skip them during load.
Some more info can help answer better.